# Convertir date SQL a dd-mmmm-yyyy C#

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

Tengo un campo `date` en una tabla de SQL, si trato de guardar, ya sea `09-02-2019` o `09-febrero-2019` el me las guarda, pero si trato de recuperar esa fecha me muestra algo asi (Pegado todo o con T):

```
2019-02-09 00:00:00.000
```

La cuestion es que estoy tratando de recuperar esos valores con EF y LINQ para poder formatear la fecha, trato de implementar esto:

**PROPIEDADES DE FECHA**

```
    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime? fechaInicio { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime? fechaExpo { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime? fechaEntrega { get; set; }
```

**LISTA DATOS**

```
//TRAER LISTA DE ORDENES
  public List<mapOrdenesListaTemp> listadoOrdenes()
  {
     var lista = new List<mapOrdenesListaTemp>();

      using(var ctx=new ModelContext())
      {
         lista = ctx.Ordenes.Select(m => new mapOrdenesListaTemp
                                    {
fechaInicio=Convert.ToDateTime(m.fechaInicio).ToString("dd-mmmm-yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
fechaExportacion= Convert.ToDateTime(m.fechaExpo).ToString("dd-mmmm-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
fechaEntrega= Convert.ToDateTime(m.fechaEntrega).ToString("dd-mmmm-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

                                     }).ToList();  

      }
```

**TRATO DE ASIGNAR LOS DATOS ACA**

```
public class mapOrdenesListaTemp
{
    public string fechaInicio { get; set; }
    public string fechaEntrega { get; set; }
    public string fechaExportacion { get; set; }
}
```

Pero me lanza este error:

> System.NotSupportedException: 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the
>   method 'System.String ToString(System.String, System.IFormatProvider)'
>   method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.'

Se que no puedo usar `.ToString()` según me esta diciendo el error, pero como hago para recuperar el dato y despues aplicarle la conversión (osea quisiera pasar la fecha de `2019-02-09` a `09-febrero-2019`? (Osea alguna forma de sortear este error, igual no se si esta correcta?)

Comment: Pregunta bro, ¿Qué tipo de dato es: fechaInicio, fechaExportacion, fechaEntrega? ¿DateTime? o ¿un String?

Comment: @fredyfx todos en SQL son `date` al traerlos son `DateTime` pero quiero pasarlos a string (por aquello de 9-febrero-2019)

Comment: Creo que la respuesta podría ser de utilidad, veamos qué pasa :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si la entidad `Ordenes` define las propiedade como `DateTime` no tiene que volver a convertirla.

Lo que indica el error es que no pude convertir a `sql` el `ToString()`, si fuera un valor numerico se podria usar el `SqlFunctions.StringConvert()` pero en este caso es una fecha

```
public List<mapOrdenesListaTemp> listadoOrdenes()
{
  var lista = new List<mapOrdenesListaTemp>();

  using(var ctx=new ModelContext())
  {
     var allOrders = ctx.Ordenes.toList();

     lista = allOrders.Select(m => new mapOrdenesListaTemp()
                                {
                                    fechaInicio= m.fechaInicio?.ToString("dd-mmmm-yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                                    fechaExportacion= m.fechaExpo?.ToString("dd-mmmm-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                                    fechaEntrega= m.fechaEntrega?.ToString("dd-mmmm-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                                 }).ToList();  

  }
```

Como verás, primero fuerza la ejecución de la query en entity framework, luego con la respuesta se aplica el mapping a la entidad de respuesta.

Veras que use el `?.` ya que esas propiedades permiten `null`, si con eso no funciona debes usar `m.fechaInicio.Value.ToString(...` ya que debes tomar el valor del campo null, aunque en realidad deberías validarlo:

```
fechaInicio= m.fechaInicio.HasValue() ? m.fechaInicio.Value.ToString("dd-mmmm-yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) : "",
```

Comment: Solo tuve que cambiar el `Culture`por que me daban en ingles, excelente respuesta!!

Answer (score 1):

Quizás esto te sea de utilidad: Coloca un `.ToList()` antes del `.Select`

```
//TRAER LISTA DE ORDENES
  public List<mapOrdenesListaTemp> listadoOrdenes()
  {
     var lista = new List<mapOrdenesListaTemp>();

      using(var ctx=new ModelContext())
      {
         lista = ctx.Ordenes.ToList().Select(m => new mapOrdenesListaTemp
                                    {
fechaInicio=Convert.ToDateTime(m.fechaInicio).ToString("dd-mmmm-yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
fechaExportacion= Convert.ToDateTime(m.fechaExpo).ToString("dd-mmmm-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
fechaEntrega= Convert.ToDateTime(m.fechaEntrega).ToString("dd-mmmm-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

                                     });  

      }
```

Explicación:

Entity Framework (EF) convierte el uso de los operadores de las consultas como Select, Where, en una consulta SQL para cargar los datos. Al llamar un método como `.ToString()`, EF no tiene un equivalente como tal en SQL, por eso lanza el error, entonces la idea es usar alguna función para procesar los datos luego de obtenerlos, un `.ToList()`, `.ToArray()` ayuda a esta finalidad; se pueden trabajar los datos porque han sido cargados en memoria.

Comment: Si trato de hacer eso me lanza este error: `No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<IKORSYSTEM.Models.mapOrdenesListaTemp>' en 'System.Collections.Generic.List<IKORSYSTEM.Models.mapOrdenesListaTemp>'. Ya existe una conversión explícita (compruebe si le falta una conversión)`